# How to add href link with passing id into FullCalendar eventRender function

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

Here I couldn't add hypertext and get redirect to another page! How can I add hypertext with passing id and redirect to another page?

```
function calender(data) {         

    if (0 !== $("#m_calendar").length) {
        spinner.hide();
        var e = moment().startOf("day");
        e.format("YYYY-MM"),
        e.clone().subtract(1, "day").format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
        e.format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
        e.clone().add(1, "day").format("YYYY-MM-DD"),

        $("#m_calendar").fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: "prev,next today", center: "title", right: "month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listWeek"
            },
            editable: !0, 
            eventLimit: !0, 
            navLinks: !0, 
            backgroundColor: !1,
            events: data, 
            eventRender: function (e, t) {
                  t.hasClass("fc-day-grid-event") ? (t.data("content", e.description).append("<a href='/dashboard/view/8>link</a>"), t.data("placement", "top"), mApp.initPopover(t)) : t.hasClass("fc-time-grid-event") ? t.find(".fc-title").append('<div class="fc-description">' + e.description + "</div>") : 0 !== t.find(".fc-list-item-title").lenght && t.find(".fc-list-item-title").append('<div class="fc-description">' + e.description + "</div>")
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: if you add the `url` property to your event's data, then fullCalendar will automatically redirect the page to that URL when the event is clicked on. You don't really need to implement that yourself. See details of the `url` property at  https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/event-object and also the bottom section of https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/eventClick

Comment: P.S. In relation to your question, I don't know exactly what you mean by you "couldn't" add hypertext? I see no attempt in your code to add a hyperlink anywhere. So it's unclear what you tried or what went wrong. You could add a link using the `append` command just like you have added other bits of HTML.

Comment: P.S. what is all this `!0` business in your code? Just write `true` or `false` if you need a boolean value.

Comment: .append("<a href='/dashboard/view/8>link</a>")
I have updated my code with append, but I need to redirect the page when I click event, but In my case, there is a text as a link!

Comment: ok sorry I didn't see that. Consider splitting your statement onto multiple lines so it's readable.

Comment: Anyway you have a simple typo. Should be `<a href='/dashboard/view/8'>link</a>` - you forgot the `'` at the end of the URL.

Comment: Also later on in that line `t.find(".fc-list-item-title").lenght` the `lenght` is a typo, should be `length`. You need to double-check your work. Also this is another reason for splitting code into multiple lines and making it more readable - it will help _you_ to read it and see mistakes (not just other people!).

Comment: I made a minimal demo showing a fixed version: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/XWmpage?editors=1010

Comment: okay thank you, but now I got a problem to passing data using different id, 

{(t.data("content", e.appointment_id).append('<a href="/dashboard/view/"'+e.appointment_id+'><span><i class="flaticon-eye" style="color:white;"></i></span></a>')

this is my updated code, I got correct id value as a popup

Comment: for the demo purpose I have checked content as </ e.appointment_id >

Comment: Again it's a typo, the second `"` needs to be after the ID, so that the ID is part of the URL string. `<a href="/dashboard/view/'+e.appointment_id+'">`. Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/wvKgqZW?editors=1010 . If you had used your browser's Element Inspector (part of the Developer Tools) to check what the HTML you've created looks like after it's been added to the page, you would probably have spotted this. (In this case, just right-click on the link and choose "Inspect" from the pop-up menu). Please ensure you understand how to debug your applications, it will save you a lot of time.

Comment: No problem. Like I said, make some time to understand the tools which are there to help you, both in terms of the debugging tools in the browser, and making sure you write your code in a maintainable way. Then you'll find you'll start solving problems like this by yourself, in a matter of seconds.